# Tridion Content Porter Error

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I am running Content Porter to import content from a package and getting the following error:

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_READ".

The complete error is:

```
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="8004033F" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Component (tcm:7-3340).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4418</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:7-3340</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="true"><![CDATA[The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.]]></tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false"><![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_READ".]]><tcm:Token>EDA_ITEMS_READ</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false"><![CDATA[Link to Schema has invalid value.]]><tcm:Token>Schema</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,DbAsyncResult)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.IsExistingObject(TcmUri)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Session.IsExistingObject(String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Utilities.AssertItemExists(TcmUri,Session)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLink(Link)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Component.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Request.SaveItem</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location>
        </tcm:CallStack>
    </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

Comment: As suggested by @user978511 in his answer, indeed it sounds to me like there might be a corruption in that specific Component for whatever reason, maybe the UI can fix it when you try to open that Component manually and try to save it.

Comment: Did the allowed schema get updated and this component hasn't been re-validated against the new field definition?

Answer (score 2):

It says:

```
Link to Schema has invalid value.
```

Which seems quite clear to me. Try to open component tcm:7-3340 and see what schema it has. Also try to save it.